# Hide current tab on active another one in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show a tab based on `href` attribute and I doing in this way:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#myTab a[href="#<?php echo $sf_user->getFlash('activeTab', 'usuarios'); ?>"].tab('show');
    });
</script>
```

The tab is showed but for some reason the active tab still there, so only the content is showd but the tab active doesn't move, any help?

Comment: single quote before #myTab is not getting close anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the selector not closing the `"` correctly.

```
$('#myTab a[href="#<?php echo $sf_user->getFlash('activeTab', 'usuarios'); ?>"].tab('show');
//                                                               Problem here ^
```

Correct way:

```
$('#myTab a[href="#<?php echo $sf_user->getFlash('activeTab', 'usuarios'); ?>"]').tab('show');
```

Add `')` before `.tab('show');`.

Comment: ohhhh didn't notice that small typo, things that happens when you try to find a big mistake :-( thanks

Comment: This would have been shown in the `JavaScript Console` right? Didn't notice it??